# elastichsearch score max_score =-1

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

when i send a query to elasticsearch below;

```
GET document_news/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "deleted_in_streams": "5b0cf5a038de881db68158ac"
              }
            }
          ],
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "streams": "5b0cf5a038de881db68158ac"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "related_in_streams": "5b0cf5a038de881db68158ac"
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "_id": [
                  "r7Drd2YBzJMWvYRxjtYd",
                  "crDtd2YBzJMWvYRxRtcE",
                  "O7Dud2YBzJMWvYRxK9tF",
                  "lbDvd2YBzJMWvYRxZ-AP",
                  "GbDvd2YBzJMWvYRxX-BE",
                  "OrDvd2YBzJMWvYRxg-Lh",
                  "97Dwd2YBzJMWvYRxcOTe",
                  "1LDwd2YBzJMWvYRxXeMk",
                  "ErDxd2YBzJMWvYRxYunY",
                  "MLDxd2YBzJMWvYRxdeqy",
                  "NLDyd2YBzJMWvYRx3f1E",
                  "n7Dxd2YBzJMWvYRxketh",
                  "iLDzd2YBzJMWvYRxCP-q",
                  "-rDyd2YBzJMWvYRxR_RH",
                  "zrDxd2YBzJMWvYRx-vBO",
                  "_rHzd2YBzJMWvYRxNQG0",
                  "o7Dyd2YBzJMWvYRxL_OG",
                  "bLHzd2YBzJMWvYRxYQTk",
                  "xbDzd2YBzJMWvYRxDP_m",
                  "gLHzd2YBzJMWvYRxGQDz",
                  "ALHzd2YBzJMWvYRxtQkn",
                  "Q7Dyd2YBzJMWvYRxy_zE",
                  "H7Hzd2YBzJMWvYRxSgNQ",
                  "zbDyd2YBzJMWvYRx-v5y",
                  "ObHzd2YBzJMWvYRxFADi",
                  "NrHzd2YBzJMWvYRxbwXT",
                  "7rHzd2YBzJMWvYRxjwZ_",
                  "GbHzd2YBzJMWvYRxpAhx",
                  "I7Hzd2YBzJMWvYRx3At5",
                  "tLHzd2YBzJMWvYRx5gun",
                  "jLH0d2YBzJMWvYRxBw3P"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": {
          "source": "params.sortOrder.indexOf(doc['_id'])",
          "lang": "painless",
          "params": {
            "sortOrder": [
              "r7Drd2YBzJMWvYRxjtYd",
              "crDtd2YBzJMWvYRxRtcE",
              "O7Dud2YBzJMWvYRxK9tF",
              "lbDvd2YBzJMWvYRxZ-AP",
              "GbDvd2YBzJMWvYRxX-BE",
              "OrDvd2YBzJMWvYRxg-Lh",
              "97Dwd2YBzJMWvYRxcOTe",
              "1LDwd2YBzJMWvYRxXeMk",
              "ErDxd2YBzJMWvYRxYunY",
              "MLDxd2YBzJMWvYRxdeqy",
              "NLDyd2YBzJMWvYRx3f1E",
              "n7Dxd2YBzJMWvYRxketh",
              "iLDzd2YBzJMWvYRxCP-q",
              "-rDyd2YBzJMWvYRxR_RH",
              "zrDxd2YBzJMWvYRx-vBO",
              "_rHzd2YBzJMWvYRxNQG0",
              "o7Dyd2YBzJMWvYRxL_OG",
              "bLHzd2YBzJMWvYRxYQTk",
              "xbDzd2YBzJMWvYRxDP_m",
              "gLHzd2YBzJMWvYRxGQDz",
              "ALHzd2YBzJMWvYRxtQkn",
              "Q7Dyd2YBzJMWvYRxy_zE",
              "H7Hzd2YBzJMWvYRxSgNQ",
              "zbDyd2YBzJMWvYRx-v5y",
              "ObHzd2YBzJMWvYRxFADi",
              "NrHzd2YBzJMWvYRxbwXT",
              "7rHzd2YBzJMWvYRxjwZ_",
              "GbHzd2YBzJMWvYRxpAhx",
              "I7Hzd2YBzJMWvYRx3At5",
              "tLHzd2YBzJMWvYRx5gun",
              "jLH0d2YBzJMWvYRxBw3P"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "size": 31,
  "from": 0
}
```

turning max_score= -1

return is below;

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 31,
    "max_score": -1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "document_news",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1LDwd2YBzJMWvYRxXeMk",
        "_score": -1,
        "_source": {
          "image": "https://dummyimage.com/800x600",
          "original_url": "https://www.sener.org/home.html",
          "streams": [
            "5b0cf5a038de881db68158ac"
          ],
          "created_at": "2018-10-15T13:35:33.154171",
          "related_in_streams": [
            "5b0cf5a038de881db68158ac"
          ],
          "source": {
            "favicon": "https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=55&txt=16x16&w=16&h=16",
            "name": "hayrioglu-bilge.com"
          },
          "is_streamed": true,
          "title": "Eum expedita facere ducimus illo.Ömer Çelik ab bakanı",
          "publish_date": "2018-10-15T16:35:33.152872",
          "is_crawled": false,
          "content": """
Cum pariatur nesciunt officiis praesentium. Ratione voluptatibus reprehenderit nam sit odio. Minima modi sint libero laudantium numquam ipsa.
Amet porro provident. Maxime distinctio minus numquam totam suscipit voluptatibus ducimus. In optio recusandae animi quam neque.
Voluptates possimus minus animi. Tempore nihil ullam voluptatibus. Ratione maxime aliquam distinctio.
Placeat quos optio aperiam. Corporis quam repudiandae fuga assumenda eligendi voluptates hic. Aperiam error provident labore quo quo id.
Quisquam maiores magni molestias rem laborum aspernatur. Dicta eveniet suscipit aliquid.Ömer Çelik ab bakanı
```

can anyone help me where i am doing wrong ?
Elasticsearch-oss 6.3.1

thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. In your script you need to change this:

```
  "script_score": {
    "script": {
      "source": "params.sortOrder.indexOf(doc['_id'].value)", <=== add .value
      "lang": "painless",
```

what happens is that `doc['_id']` in the script has type of [`org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.Strings`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.0.1/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.Strings.html) and when you call an [`.indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) it expects a `java.lang.String`.

#### Why do I get max_score=-1?

It's because `indexOf()` does not find the corresponding list element.

Roughly speaking, painless language is a sandboxed Java-based scripting language, so it inherits most of Java behavior. In this case, [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)) goes over a `List` of `String`s and does a call to `.equals()`:

> Returns the index of the last occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More
>   formally, returns the highest index i such that (o==null ?
>   get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

And [`.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) in turn is usually implemented so it returns true if and only if both objects have same type.

In our case it is enough to add `.value` so the ID of the document is returned as a `String`.

Hope that helps!